# It can be use in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: epplus

I was wondering if EPPLus can be use in Visual Studio 2019. I was looking into others Nugets but this is the most relevant for what I need. I saw in the Nuget Gallery (https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) that it is usefull in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPPLus is a nuget package, it is not linked to Visual studio version but on your code target. So you can use it in VS 2019.

I'm using it in my current project in .NET Core API

Comment: I also use without issues

Answer (score 0):

I can see the OP accepted the previous answer but here is a more detailed answer just in case anybody needs it in the future.

From Package Manager Console in an open project

**Install-Package EPPlus**

If you do not know where to access Package Manager Console from
Navigate to Tools / Nuget Package Manager / Package Manager Console
Then run the above command

or

Right click dependencies in the project and select Manage Nuget Packages
 [image: Right Click Image]

in the browse tab enter EPPlus